# Slider range and checkbox

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, rangeslider

Здравствуйте! Подскажите, пожалуйста, как можно связать динамически слайдер диапазона с чекбоксами? То есть при нажатии на определенный чекбокс отображаем изменения на слайдере и наоборот.

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <script>
  $( function() {
    $( "#slider-range" ).slider({
      range: true,
      min: 0,
      max: 10,
      values: [ 1, 4 ],
     slide: function( event, ui ) {
            $( "#amount" ).val( ui.values[ 0 ] );
            $( "#amount2" ).val( ui.values[ 1 ] );
        }
    });

    $("#amount").change(function() {
        $("#slider-range").slider('values',0,$(this).val());
    });

    $("#amount2").change(function() {
        $("#slider-range").slider('values',1,$(this).val());
    });



  } );


  </script>
</head>
<body>



<input type="checkbox" id="amount" value="3">
<input type="checkbox" id="amount2" value="9">
<div id="slider-range"></div>




</body>
</html>
```

[image: Пример]